# how do i add libraries to runtime classpath in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

Im new to using eclipse and developing plugins in general. With that said, I added jxl.jar to my lib dir and as a user library in my project. It compiles successfully in eclipse and runs on my system, but it cannot find the imported jxl classes on the user system. I am lost at how to add the jxl.jar to the end users classpath. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: is you project a dynamic web project type?

Comment: I do not believe so, it compiles to a jar and the other special extension is .gplugin which is just for easier installation into the program the plugin developed for (geneious)